# winapi - how to get a control RECT structure from the resource file

Tags: winapi

I create a dialog window with some controls based on the resource file using CreateDialog function. Then I can get a control handle this way:

```
HWND ctrlHwnd = GetDlgItem(dlgHwnd, IDC_LIST);
```

and get a control dimensions using functions like GetClientRect etc. Let's assume that using SetWindowPos I change a control dimension. Is there any way to get initial dimensions from the resource file ? I know that I can save an initial RECT data in my program memory but I wonder if there is other way ?

Comment: You can read a [DIALOGEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/dialogex-resource) resource like any other resource. That's the binary representation of a [DLGTEMPLATEEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dlgtemplateex) structure. Its `cx` and `cy` fields hold the width and height, respectively, in DLU. You can use [MapDialogRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapdialogrect) to translate those into screen pixel values.

Comment: Likewise for the individual [DLGITEMTEMPLATEEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dlgitemtemplateex) structures following the `DLGTEMPLATEEX` structure. There's one for each control defined in the dialog resource. The `id` field holds the control identifier (like `IDC_LIST` in your example).

Comment: [Raymond Chen: The evolution of dialog templates – 32-bit Classic Templates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040621-00/?p=38793) via [mity /
old-new-win32api](https://github.com/mity/old-new-win32api#dialog-templates)